# Puppet: Client is not connected to master - cert sign request does not appear

Tags: puppetmaster, puppet-agent

at the moment I'm having trouble with a new host that should be connected to the `puppet-master`.

The cert-sign request does not appear:

```
[root@puppet sudoers.d]# puppet cert list
[root@puppet sudoers.d]#
```

What can I do here?

Comment: What does the client log say? How is the client configured?

Comment: Hello, the client is configured according to a tutorial of digital ocean. I edited puppet.conf and added "[agent] server = my.puppet-server.com" Now the request is visible in puppet and foreman, I signed it but the host does not appear in foreman's host-list.